# ADD Down Arrow Symbol in Submenu VB 6.0

Tags: vb6, submenu

Could help me to make my menu looks like the following example:

```
    Menu ▼
      Submenu1 ►
        Submenu
      Submenu2 ►
        Submenu
```

I'm using the Menu Editor , but I get show down arrow symbol,also use Visual Basic 6.0.

Thanks...

Comment: If it's `vb6` then why did you also tag it as `vb.net`?

Comment: Excuse me i´m noob in this forum

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The toplevel menu wont show an arrow, that is implied by it being a menu.  A submenu will show an arrow automatically if there are sub items

Comment: @Plutonix In vb 6 its possible, y going to upload a photo, wait me a second please.

Comment: Excuse @Plutonix but i need to have 10 of reputation for POST images. I have the screens of this project but i dont have the code, i only need replicate this screens in a new  project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This menu is with a extra "component" of vb6.

It is **"Sheridan Activetoolbars Plus 2.0"**

Thanks for u atenction.

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google of "how to use the vb6 menu editor" returned plenty of good sites and videos that explain.

Here is the Microsoft [site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262293(v=vs.60).aspx) explaining using the editor

Comment: Thanks i use this tuto for guide me but i cant get menu.